# How to copy table structure from defaultview.table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a datatable with three columns. I am sorting the data

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();

DataColumn auto = new DataColumn("ID",typeof(System.Int32));
                        dt.Columns.Add(auto);
                        auto.AutoIncrement = true;            
                        auto.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
                        auto.ReadOnly = true;
 dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["ID"] }; 
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Precedence",typeof(System.Int32))); 

DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                dv.Sort = "Precedence ASC";
                dt=dv.table
```

dv.table doesnot return me table structure of original table.I want the sorted data and the table schema(primary key) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If  you user `dt=dv.table` it assign a reference of `dv` to `dt`

user copy() method to copy Datatable instead of assign table

```
dt = dv.Table.Copy();
```